# vision_ssd_detect does not detect

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA8 and caffe installed properly:

- `vision_ssd_detect` node runs (using provided launch) without any warnings
- nvidia-smi says that it uses approximately 600MB of 1080ti's video memory regardless of image_raw resolution (compared 1920x1200 with 320x200)
- rqt_graph shows that `vision_ssd_detect` node subscribed to the right topic

But nevertheless, [vision_ssd_detect](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_perception/tree/master/vision_ssd_detect) does not return any detected objects:

- `rostopic echo /detection/image_detector/objects` command returns messages with empty list of objects, here's full message example: `header:  seq: 426 stamp:  secs: 1562840561 nsecs: 831216836 frame_id: "cam_fc_near" objects: []`
- Hence Image Viewer Plugin does not show any activity on image

It is worth noting that YOLOv3 from vision_darknet_detect works properly, here's the example of its `/detection/image_detector/objects` message:

### `    header:
seq: 187
stamp:
secs: 1562840690
nsecs: 964700791
frame_id: "cam_fc_near"
objects:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs:         0
  frame_id: ''
id: 0
label: "traffic light"
score: 0.666867136955
color: 
  r: 0.0
  g: 0.0
  b: 0.0
  a: 0.0
valid: True...
...behavior_state: 0
user_defined_info: []
```

`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329790/vision_ssd_detect-does-not-detect/) by [sergiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/44436/sergiev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-08-05**:
Can you please share?

1. Autoware version
2. SSD Caffe hash commit
3. Link to the prototext and pretrained model weights you're using
4. Output log of `vision_ssd_detect`. (Please use pastebin or some service to share the file)

So we can try to reproduce your problem?

**Comment by [sergiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/44436/sergiev/) on 2019-08-05**:\

1. I'm using Autoware 1.12, it was set up [according official instruction](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build)
2. `git rev-parse HEAD` returned `4817bf8b4200b35ada8ed0dc378dceaf38c539e4`
3. all prototxts and caffemodel described [here](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd/models/bvlc_googlenet)
4. [here's the output log of `roslaunch vision_ssd_detect vision_ssd_detect_launch`](https://pastebin.com/HZj9VFXQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for sharing the information.

Looking at your files. The problem is you're using Vanilla Caffe GoogleNet classification models, not the SSD detection models.

Please download the ones from the SSD's README repo marked as COCO from here:
https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd#models

These links:

- COCO SSD300: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzKzrI_SkD1_NDlVeFJDc2tIU1k
- COCO SSD512: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzKzrI_SkD1_TW4wTC14aDdCTDQ

Finally, before launching **delete** the lines `1607` to `1609` from the `deploy.prototxt` file included in the tar file.

(Remove these lines =>)

```
    save_output_param {
      label_map_file: "data/VOC0712/labelmap_voc.prototxt"
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) with karma: 136 on 2019-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huifeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/46984/huifeng/) on 2019-10-11**:
I tried with COCO SSD512 model (my autoware version is autoware_v1_10 and cuda 9.0). Still there is no detected object. No warning and error  are in log. Do you know if there is anything more that I can try? thx